# C++ `using` command for type alias in template class

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, using

This seems like it should be really simple, but I've been playing and havn't found the solution I'm looking for yet, so here goes:

I have the following struct (simplified for illustrative purposes of course):

```
template<typename T>
struct test
    {
    using L = std::list<T>;
    L::iterator a;
    };
```

Now, this throws the error:

```
error: need 'typename' before 'test<T>::K::iterator' because 'test<T>::K' is a dependent scope
```

The two ways I have found of fixing it so far are both less than ideal:

**1)** add typename before any use of L:

```
template<typename T>
struct test
    {
    using L = std::list<T>;
    typename L::iterator a;
    };
```

I'd rather avoid the extra verbosity of this if possible.

**2)** add another using statement to target the iterator directly:

```
template<typename T>
struct test
    {
    using L = std::list<T>;
    using iter = typename L::iterator;
    iter a;
    };
```

But that would require having to do the same for every iterator I wanted to use, if I also wished to access the `const_iterator` etc etc, and I'd rather not have to define a bunch of using statements.

So, is there a way to write the using statement that then allows me to write:

```
 L::iterator a;
 L::const_iterator b;
 ...
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `typename` must be there, but you can use a couple of **alias template** utilities to avoid defining a new `iter` type every time:

```
template<typename C>
using Iterator = typename C::iterator;

template<typename C>
using ConstIterator = typename C::const_iterator;

template<typename T>
struct test
{
    using L = std::list<T>;
    Iterator<L> i;
    ConstIterator<L> ci;
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! In light of not being able to do it my preferred way, this looks to be the cleanest way to go about it :)

Answer (score 2):

Nope, there is not.  All dependent types must either be prefaced with `typename`, or be brought in via a preface with `typename`.

Now, you could create a `list_iter<T>` `using` declartion somewhere:

```
template<typename T>
using list_iter = typename std::list<T>::iterator;
```

or even a meta-iter using statement:

```
template<template<typename>class container, typename T>
using iter = typename container<T>::iterator;
template<template<typename>class container, typename T>
using const_iter = typename container<T>::const_iterator;
```

which would let you do:

```
struct test {
  using L = std::list<T>;
  iter<std::list,T> a;
};
```

where I've "hidden" the `typename` in a `using` declaration outside of the `struct`.

As an aside, 99% of the time `std::list` is the wrong container.

Comment: I think this would not work, because `std::list` also accepts an additional allocator type parameter (which has a default argument)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! As for using a list, It's going to be a potentially very large list of symbols that will often need to be removed or inserted at locations saved somewhere else (so traversing the list to find them is no concern); I think this is one of those 1% cases :)

Comment: If you are traversing the `list` to find them before deleting them, and they aren't all clustered at or near the front of the list, then `vector` remains more efficient.  For `list` to win out, you basically need to be adding and deleting elements from it *without traversing to find the elements*, because the cost of "shifting" the elements down in a `vector` is often cheaper than the cost of traversing a `list`!  (expensive to move (ie, no move, and large copies) elements can also make `list` more tempting, but even then `deque` wins out...) If you have not profiled, you are wrong.